# R9 280 driver error not recognised on multiple R9 380 rig

Tags: mining

I am on `Windows 7 SP1 64 Bit`.

I have a rig with 6 GPUS. 5 of them are R9 380s with the `Open CL version 2.0`. I also have a R9 280 which uses version `Open CL version 1.2`

After installing the `Catalyst 15.11 Beta` driver, only the 380s get recognised leaving out the 280 with an error code 43 and a yellow triangle on Device Manager.

[image]

The error reads out as follows:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems.(Code 43)
```

Which is the best way to solve this?

Inputs from anyone with the same config would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is the name of your computer, code 43 probably means that winter is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to start then control panel, add remove programs and get rid of that beta driver. Windows is notorious for giving people issues with that 6th GPU. Switch to Linux. Yull get better has rates and because most of the open source community uses linux yull get better support. May I suggest ubuntu 15 with fglrx updates drivers installed. There a step by step guides out there that are easy to follow. Avoid ubuntu 16 for now. No official AMD support in that version and it's unknown if current github software for gpu mining rigs on linux would even work. I use an even older version of linux 14.04 but it's stable and works great, no crashes, no issues. I don't even have monitors or keyboards hooked up to my rigs. I manage them remotely through a secure encrypted tunnel. So easy solution roll back drivers but best solution is use Linux to mine with. Yull get 5% increase in mining performance.

Oh and go in your bios and disable that on board video controller. I just noticed that. It wreaks havoc and confused windows.